# Cross Sections or slices of 3d figures - Mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am trying to get a cross-section of a 3d figure to show behavior of the functions at certain the values. However I only found `SliceContourPlot3D` which works for contour plots but not regular 3d plots. Is it way to generate cross sections ? For example the cross section of the graph

```
a0 = 10; r = 2; L0 = 0.5;
Plot3D[{Tan[
    x L0 Sqrt[-1 + y^2 a0^2]] - (Sqrt[1 - y^2]/Sqrt[y^2 a0^2 - 1]
       r )}, {x, 0.1, 10}, {y, 1/a0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 20, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-1, 2}}]
```

[image]

cut by a plane z=0 .

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: you want the cross section in a separate 2d plot, or overlayed on the 3d graphics?

Comment: In a separate 2d plot would be perfect

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{
   Show[{
     Plot3D[{Tan[
         x L0 Sqrt[-1 + y^2 a0^2]] - (Sqrt[1 - y^2]/
           Sqrt[y^2 a0^2 - 1] r)}, {x, 0.1, 10}, {y, 1/a0, 1}, 
      PlotPoints -> ControlActive[5, 20], PlotRange -> {-1, 10}, 
      AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}],
     Graphics3D[{Blue, Opacity[0.5], 
       HalfPlane[{{0, 0, z}, {10, 0, z}}, {0, 1, 0}]}]
     }, ImageSize -> 300],
   ContourPlot[
    Tan[x L0 Sqrt[-1 + y^2 a0^2]] - (Sqrt[1 - y^2]/
         Sqrt[y^2 a0^2 - 1] r) == z, {x, 0.1, 10}, {y, 0.11, 1}, 
    PlotPoints -> ControlActive[5, 20], ImageSize -> 300]
   }],
 {z, 0, 10} ]
```

yielding the following:

[image]

The left panel shows the position of the cutting plane, and the right one - the cross-section of the 3D plot. Take care to wait a bit after you have moved the slider.

Have fun!

Comment: I was thinking it could be done mathematically using heavyside functions. But this solves my problem.

Thank you very much !!!

Comment: @John David  For Mma it is typical that a problem can be solved with multiple approaches, and one chooses the approach that is closer to him. May be that the Heaviside functions will also give a solution.

Comment: Your version is exactly what I need. Again Thank you very much for your time.