# How to plot a crossection of a ParametricPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, intersection

I'm plotting a surface using ParametricPlot3D. Ideally I would like to plot an intersection of the surface with a plane just as seen in another question ([Cross Sections or slices of 3d figures - Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153769/cross-sections-or-slices-of-3d-figures-mathematica)). However in my case the parameters u and v are not equivalent to the spatial coordinates x,y. This is why i tried RegionPlot in place of CountourPlot to plot all pairs (x,y) that intersect the surface for a given value of z. This is not working somehow and I'm lost trying to look for alternatives.

```
Surface[u_, v_] = {Cos[u], Sin[u] + Cos[v], Sin[v]};

Row[{Show[{ParametricPlot3D[
     Surface[u, v], {u, 0, 2Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}, 
     PlotStyle -> Opacity[ 0.2]], 
    Graphics3D[{Blue, Opacity[0.4], 
      InfinitePlane[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]}]}, 
   ImageSize -> 300], 
  RegionPlot[
   Exists[{u, v}, Surface[u, v] == {x, y, 0}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
    ImageSize -> 300]}]
```

[image]

In reality my surface is a bit more complicated so I chose a simple one for posing this question. Also ideally I would like to be able to change around the normal vector of the plane later, checking out any angle of the crosssection I like, so please keep that in mind when thinking about the question.
Thank you very much for any engagement in my problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) + [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) + [`MeshStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshStyle.html) to mark the intersection of the plane with the surface:

```
pp = ParametricPlot3D[Surface[u, v], {u, -Pi, Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}, 
      PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3], 
      PlotPoints -> 200, 
      MeshFunctions -> { #3 &}, 
      Mesh -> {{{10^-6, Red}}}];

 Show[pp, Graphics3D[{Blue, Opacity[0.4], 
   InfinitePlane[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]}]]
```

[image]

Extract the line primitives from `pp` and remove the last column of coordinates to get 2D lines to be used with `Graphics`:

```
Graphics[{Red, Thick,  Cases[Normal[pp], Line[x_] :> Line[x[[All, ;; 2]]], All]}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Use (1) `MeshFunctions -> { #2 &}` in `ParametricPlot3D`, (2) `InfinitePlane[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0,0,1}}]` in `Graphics3D` and (3) `Line[x[[All, {1,3}]]]` in `Cases` to get

[image][image]

And `MeshFunctions -> { #2-# &}`, `InfinitePlane[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 1, 0}, {0,0,1}}]`, `] :> Line[x[[All, {1,3}]]]` to get

[image]

[image]

**Update:** You can use any (not necessarily linear) function of 5 arguments ({`x, y, z, u, v}`) as the value of the `MeshFunction` option. Also you can use [`MeshShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshShading.html) to have different styles for mesh divisions:

```
pp = ParametricPlot3D[Surface[u, v], {u, -Pi, Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3], PlotPoints -> 200, 
  MeshFunctions -> { -2 Pi # + #2 Sin[# + 3 #2] + Cos@#3 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{{0, Directive[Thick, Red]}}}, 
  MeshShading -> {Opacity[.3, Green], Automatic}]
```

[image]

Use `ContourPlot3D` with the mesh function as the first argument to get the separating surface and `Show` with `pp`:

```
cp = ContourPlot3D[-2 Pi x + y Sin[x + 3 y] + Cos@z == 0,
   {x, -1, 1}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -1, 1}, 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[.5, Red], Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None];

Show[pp, cp]
```

[image]

Comment: I ended up using this, thanks a lot!

Comment: @joe, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: thank you. I adapted most of my stuff to your approach. just one last thing. i don't quite understand how I'm supposed to manipulate the part Cases[Normal[pp], Line[x_] :> Line[x[[All, ;; 2]]] when I change the direction of my plane. I have never used the functions Cases or Line before so I'm not quite sure, what the arguments do when you change them. I also haven't learned much from the documentation. Maybe you can give me a hint.

Comment: I figured something out Cases[Normal[pp], 
 Line[x_] :> Line[Map[R2.R1.#1 &, x][[All, {1, 2}]]], All] where R2 and R1 are rotation matrices that turn {0,0,1} into the normal vector of the plane. Seems to be working.

Answer (score 4):

Here my solutionapproach

First define the plane e and n

```
n = {0, 0, 1}; (*normalvector of plane*)
e = {0, 0, 0}; (*point of plane*)
```

Condition of intersection is `Surface[u, v] - e).n == 0` which can be visualized with

```
ContourPlot[(Surface[u, v] - e).n == 0, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -1.1 Pi ,1.1 Pi }, FrameLabel -> {u, v},PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-1.1 Pi, 1.1 Pi}}]
```

[image]

Obviously the intersection is defined by `0<u<2Pi ,v \[Element] {0, Pi}` (which could be evaluated by `NSolve[{(Surface[u, v] - e).n == 0,0 <= u <= 2 Pi, -Pi <= v <= Pi}, {u, v}, Reals]`):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Surface[u, 0], Surface[u, Pi]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

It's not necessary to introduce new coordinates `x,y`.

**2nd example**:

```
n={0,1,0};
sol = NSolve[{(Surface[u, v] - e).n == 0,0 <= u <= 2 Pi, -Pi < v < Pi}, {u, v}, Reals] 
ParametricPlot3D[Surface[u, v] /. sol, {u, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: ok, thank you, I like the start of this. But what about the plane for n = {0, 1, 0}; though? The contour lines will not be constant in any coordinate u or v. So I can't just produce the second plot by putting constant numbers into the Surface function.

Comment: something I'm trying now to expand on your approach is the following

uvlines = ImplicitRegion[(Surface[u, v] - e).n == 0, {u, v}]
ParametricPlot3D[Surface[u, v], Element[{u, v}, uvlines]]

but again, it's not working.

Comment: @joe NSolve gives you the parametric solution!  You have to put the NSolve result into the `ParametricPlot3D`

Comment: @joe I edited my answer...